# How to drop annotations on a map view and save the pin

Tags: swift, mapkit

I want to code an APP where the User can drop a pin on the map by pressing on the map. After the pin is dropped, I want to save the pin into an database. I don't care in which one maybe with `Realm` or `CoreData`.

Comment: I think this is a perfect tutorial for you https://www.raywenderlich.com/112544/realm-tutorial-getting-started. There you create a map-based app with Realm as the data storage

Comment: the tutorial seems perfekt thank you. I will try this now

Answer (score 0):

RTFM

Can't really help you without any code, or any problem.

some links that can be helpfull :
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html
https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497

come back after you try something ;)

EDIT:

You defined a gesture recognizer inside your `viewDidLoad` method, put it directly in your controller instead, that should remove some errors :

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create a gesture recognizer for long presses (for example in viewDidLoad)
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
        lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 0.5; //user needs to press for half a second.
        [self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
    }

    - (void)handleLongPress:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
        if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
            return;
        }
        CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.mapView];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate = [self.mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];
        MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        point.coordinate = touchMapCoordinate;
        for (id annotation in self.mapView.annotations) {
            [self.mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
        }
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: I now get the Error expected expression in list of expressions in the line UILongPressGestureRecognisezer *lpgr... and an error expected declaration in the line - (void)handleLongPress:...I don't really know whats wrong with my code

Comment: There was an equal sign missing